# Best practise for returning a variable that goes through a branching path?

Tags: c++

Is it better to have a return statement at the end of each path?

```
int foo( int B ) {
  int A{ 0 };
  if ( A > B ) {
    doSomething(A);
    return A;
  }
  doSomethingElse(A);
  return A;
}
```

Or is it better having one return statement at the end?

```
int foo( int B ) {
  int A{ 0 };
  if ( A > B ) {
    doSomething(A);
  } else {
    doSomethingElse(A);
  }
  return A;
}
```

Comment: I suppose this is probably opinion-based, but IMO there is nothing wrong with having multiple return statements. In fact, they can even help to reduce indentation making code look clearer.

Comment: I don't think it's opinion based. There's an interesting video on youtube about this in c++ weekly series of Jason Turner

Comment: The behavior is the same, so the question is which is more readable? In my opinion, the second is more readable but that's a matter of opinion.

Comment: Personally I would change the functions to return, then your function could becomes `if ( A > B ) return doSomething(A); else return doSomethingElse(A);`

Comment: watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9mWWNYRHAIQ)

Comment: I am voting top re-open the quistion, because it is really not opinion based. There are good technical reasons to prefer one approach after another, and idiomatic C++ code uses those.

Comment: @Deumaudit That video is pretty specific, I don't see how it applied here.

Comment: @SergeyA I'll vote to reopen if you can provide evidence of that. As far as I know, there is no community convention on this. And there shouldn't be any technical reasons to prefer one over the other, they both return a function local object `int A`. Both versions should compile to the same assembly.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux case described in question was mention there

Comment: @Deumaudit Can you please give me the timestamp? I watched the whole thing and didn't see it.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux industry is certainly settled on early returns. They make for objectively more readable code. Aversion to early returns comes from languages without predictable destructors and thus impossibility to implement RAI/SBRI idioms. In C++ there is simply no reason to produce multiple indentation blocks which are impossible to read when a simple early return would do.

Comment: @SergeyA It's debatable whether this qualifies as early return or not. If `A > B` is an expected successful case, then both outputs are equally the successful path. Since both path return the same result, I would argue that this is the case and that early return is not applicable here. It looks to me like the `if` is simply deciding what processing to do with `A`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux fair enough. I can see how the question can be read both ways due to lack of context.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux well, start from the beggining(timecode 0:20) "prefer either a one single return path from the function or multiple return paths" or code example on timecode 00:30 which is basically the same as in question